# How to override items per page in cloned view?

Tags: views, 8, paging

I have some Views page and there is a pager with 10 items limit per page. I cloned this View and I want to have 6 items per page in this cloned View, but this is not possible. Every time I try to change it, it's changed on the main View as well.

How I can override this for cloned View? Is there any way to do it programmatically somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the Views UI.

Click on `Display a specific number of items`

Then at top in **For** select `This block/page (override)`

[image]

**PS:** When you add fields, contextual filters, etc... anything under/besides a **BOLD/Bold** section, you need to do this there too, as each section has its own **For** setting.

Comment: oh, I need to override the pager for that View before I change the number of items...thank you...